# Toolbar(Navigation drawer) не отображается в фрагменте

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Прошу помощи с моей проблемкой. Пытаюсь разобраться с работой Navigation drawer. Создал проект, в стартовой активити тулбар виден, дровер работает нормально. Но при переходе на фрагмент - пропадает. Т.е. я могу его "вытянуть", но хочу чтобы он еще был виден. Подскажите, где и что нужно дописать:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (id == R.id.nav_trade_screen) {
            setTitle("Trade screen");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_coin_info) {
            setTitle("Information");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_accounts) {
            setTitle("Accounts");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            setTitle("Settings");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
            setTitle("Login");
            fragment = new LoginFragment();
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

LoginFragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    public LoginFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

login_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/login_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/welcome_text"
            android:textColor="@color/color_main"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: если я правильно понял вы хотите чтобы ваше меню постоянно висело, а основное содержимое экрана менялось?

Comment: Именно так. я вроде бы делал все как в примере, но тулбар не отображается

Comment: я добавил ответ, если что-то не будет понятно, спрашивайте и не стесняйтесь

Comment: Cпасибо вам за помощь!! я разобрался в своем вопросе. Как оказалось, я в методе onNavigationItemSelected подставлял не правильный id в fragmentManager. Еще раз большое спасибо - я два дня искал ошибку))

Comment: то есть вам ответ я так понял ничем особо не помог?)))

Comment: почему? я сверял свой код с вашим(они однотипные) и нашел ошибку

Comment: я понял, фрагменты в меню приблизительно одинаковые)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работа с `NavigationDrawer` требует учета очень многих факторов, чтобы в результате работало так как нам нужно. Для реализации вашей задумки лично я использовал фрагменты. Я надеюсь у вас уже есть все нужные фрагменты, и вам вероятнее всего нужно просто показывать их содержимое. Возможно вы видели, что при создании такого вида меню, студия автоматически создает огромное количество файлов каждый из которых выполняет определенную задачу. Ваши фрагменты будут меняться в специальном макете - `FrameLayout`. Поэтому если вы не вручную создавали каждый файл, то у вас должен быть файлик `content_main.xml` там по-умолчанию будет разметка `LinearLayout` и вам нужно его поменять на `FrameLayout`, вот как у меня например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Screens.MessageCenter"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_message_center">

</FrameLayout>
```

дальше вы должны каким-то образом менять фрагменты в главном макете. У вас есть пункты меню при нажатии на которые вам я так понял нужно увидеть определенный фрагмент. Поэтому идем в главный класс и начинаем работать там. Вот мой класс:

```
public class MessageCenter extends AppCompatActivity
        implements MessageList.OnFragmentInteractionListener, OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    TextView txt1, txt2;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_center);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FabSpeedDial fabSpeedDial = findViewById(R.id.fab_but);
        fabSpeedDial.setMenuListener(new FabSpeedDial.MenuListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareMenu(NavigationMenu navigationMenu) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("Write to your consultant")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MessageCenter.this, WriteResponseMess.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("Write to some e-mail")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MessageCenter.this, "Write to some e-mail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuClosed() {

            }
        });


        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);


        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View view) {
                getPersonalData();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Integer i = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
        switch (i) {
            case 0:

                try {
                    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.received).setChecked(true);
                    MessageList messageList = new MessageList();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("type", 0);
                    messageList.setArguments(bundle);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, messageList).commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case 1:

                try {
                    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.outcome).setChecked(true);
                    MessageList messageList = new MessageList();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("type", 1);
                    messageList.setArguments(bundle);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, messageList).commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 2:

                try {
                    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.draft).setChecked(true);
                    MessageList messageList = new MessageList();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("type", 2);
                    messageList.setArguments(bundle);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, messageList).commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:

                try {
                    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.received).setChecked(true);
                    MessageList messageList = new MessageList();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("type", 0);
                    messageList.setArguments(bundle);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, messageList).commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.received) {

            try {
                MessageList messageList = new MessageList();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("type", 0);
                messageList.setArguments(bundle);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, messageList).commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else if (id == R.id.outcome) {
            try {

                MessageList messageList = new MessageList();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("type", 1);
                messageList.setArguments(bundle);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, messageList).commit();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.draft) {
            try {

                MessageList messageList = new MessageList();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("type", 2);
                messageList.setArguments(bundle);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, messageList).commit();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    private void getPersonalData() {
    }

    public void updateToken() {

    }

    public APIService apiService() {

    }

    public void logOut() {

    }
}
```

у меня есть один фрагмент, и на него я передаю данные для запуска определенных функций. Дальше я немного заморочился, чтобы у меня показывался определенный пункт меню при выборе фрагмента, и так же какой пункт будет по умолчанию выбираться. 
Код моего фрагмента:

public class MessageList extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList;
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
SharedPreferences sp;
Integer type, offset;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_received, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        type = bundle.getInt("type");
    }
    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_res);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    getMessages(type);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.refresh_2);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    getMessages(type);
}

public void getMessages(final int type) {

}

public void updateToken() {


}


public void logOut() {

}


public APIService apiService() {

}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
}
```

}

Если что-то будет не понятно, то буду рад вам рассказать. Надеюсь хоть чем-то я вам помог. Удачи :)

Comment: Есть пару вопросов: 1)почему нужно использовать именно Framelayout? 2) что вы делаете в цикле switch? ведь вроде тоже самое делается в методе onNavigationItemSelected

Comment: И, если можно, покажите сам код фрагмента MessageList? я так понял, у вас все данные добавляются в один фрагмент?

Comment: я его использовал, потому-что он самый легкий из всех разметок, но так же я уже много где читаю что это самый идеальный вариант для использования фрагментов. Я думаю что вы можете использовать любой удобный вам шаблон, но я вам советую использовать именно этот определенный, у вас будет очень быстро перерисовываться содержимое, и я думаю что устройству будет легче

Comment: @Snuf, я дополнил ответ, посмотрите, если что-то будет непонятно, спрашивайте не стесняйтесь

Comment: вы спрашиваете за метод `switch` который находится в классе меню в методе `onCreate`?

Comment: Да. там вроде данные дублируются, если я правильно понял.

Comment: да там данные данные дублируются, это все сделано для удовлетворения только одной цели - как вы возможно поняли у меня есть три вида сообщений, и если я возвращаюсь с активити для просмотра сообщений, то мне нужно возвращаться на ту вкладку меню с которой я делал переход. То есть при старте активити у меня уже идет проверка на входящую переменную, но по умолчанию там стоит настройка на определенную вкладку